# Introduction Mathematical Statistics, finding the Mean Square Error of estimators

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

**I'm working on a problem from my introduction to mathematical statistics course. So far, I've done the following work:**

Let $X_{1},...,X_{m}$ and $Y_{1},...,Y_{n}$ be independent samples form the Bernoulli distribution with unknown parameter $p \in [0,1]$.

i) Prove that $(\bar{X}+\bar{Y})/2$ and $(\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})/(m+n)$ are unbiased estimators for $p$.

ii) Which of these two estimators is preferable (if $m \neq n$)?\

**Solution i)**
First we state the definition of an unbiased estimator. *An estimator T is called unbiased for the estimation of $g(\theta)$ if $E_{\theta}T=g(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$. The bias is defined as $E_{\theta}T-g(\theta).$*

We now compute $E_{p}(\bar{X}+\bar{Y})/2$ as follows,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        E_{p}(\bar{X}+\bar{Y})/2 &= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}E_{p}\frac{X_{i}}{2} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}E_{p}\frac{Y_{i}}{2}\\
        &= \frac{1}{m}m\frac{1}{2}p+\frac{1}{n}n\frac{1}{2}p\\
        &= \frac{1}{2}p+\frac{1}{2}p\\
        &=p,
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
which is equal to $g(p)$ and therefore this estimator is unbiased.

Now we look at the second estimator, $(\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})/(m+n)$, and proceed as before. \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        E_{p}\left((\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})/(m+n)\right) &= \frac{1}{m+n}E_{p}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}\right)\\
        &= \frac{1}{m+n}(mp+np)\\
        &=\frac{p(m+n)}{m+n}\\
        &= p,
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
which again is equal to $g(p)$ and therefore this estimator is unbiased.

**Solution ii)** In order to determine which of the given estimators is preferable, we desire the smallest possible *mean square error* (MSE). The MSE is defined as $$MSE(\theta;T)=E_{\theta}||T-g(\theta)||^{2}.$$

**So this is my work so far. I still don't quite understand the meaning of the estimators. Let alone, work out which one is more preferable. I've just try to work from the definition and I think my solution for i) works but I'm not sure. But for ii) I've truely no idea where to start. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!**

Comment: For (ii), I would pick as preferable the estimator that exhibits the least variance. I think that, in your case, this estimator is $\frac{\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{2}$.

Comment: How do you know this form the given definition?

Comment: Can you express the minimum squared error as a function of the bias and the variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the mean squared error can be expanded as (using linearity of expectation):
$$
\mathrm{MSE}(\theta; T) = \mathbb{E}(T^2) + \mathbb{E}(g(\theta)^2)
-2 \mathbb{E}(T g(\theta))
$$

In your case, $g(\theta)$ is just the population mean $p$, and additionally $\mathbb{E}(T) = p$, so we may rewrite

$$
\mathrm{MSE} = \mathbb{E}(T^2) + p^2 - 2p\mathbb{E}(T) =
\mathbb{E}(T^2) - p^2 = \mathbb{E}(T^2) - [\mathbb{E}(T)]^2
= \mathrm{Var}(T).
$$

It is then straightforward to calculate which of the two estimators has minimum variance, using the fact that $X_i, Y_i$ are all independent.
For example, for the estimator $\frac{\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{2}$, we get

$$
\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{\bar{X} + \bar{Y}}{2}\right) =
\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{1}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^m X_i + \frac{1}{2n}
 \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \right) =
\frac{1}{4m^2} \sum_{i=1}^m \mathrm{Var}(X_i) +
\frac{1}{4n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var}(Y_i) \\
= p(1 - p) \left( \frac{1}{4m} + \frac{1}{4n} \right)
$$

where we've used the independence of all $X_i, Y_i$ to interchange variance with summation, the property that $\mathrm{Var}(aX) = a^2 \mathrm{Var}(X)$ when $a$ is a constant, and the fact that all variables are identically distributed as $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$ to pull out the common factor $p(1 - p)$ out of the sum.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will work this out after work. Appreciate the help. I wasn't familiar with the linearity of expectation, I'll look into that later.

Comment: @Mathbeginner: you are implicitly appealing to linearity of expectation in your own proof, when you write $\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_i \mathbb{E}(X_i)$.

Comment: I did this without much thought, for me it was common sense that this would hold... Thanks :)

Comment: No worries! Consider marking the answer as accepted if it resolved your problem.

Comment: I definitely will, but I'm not quite done. When I try to find the variances:
$Var(p_{1})=E\left(\left(\frac{\bar{X}+\bar{Y}}{2}\right)^{2}\right)-E\left(\left(\frac{\bar{X}+\bar{Y}}{2}\right)\right)^{2}=E(p_{1}^{2})-(E(p_{1}))^{2}=p_{1}^{2}-p_{1}^{2})=0$, but when I try the same method for the second estimator I get:$Var(p_{2})=E\left(\left((\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})/(m+n)\right)^{2}\right)-\left(E\left((\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})/(m+n)\right)\right)^{2}=E\left(\left((\sum_{i=1}^{m}X_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j})/(m+n)\right)^{2}\right)-p^{2}$. Stuck right here.

Comment: @Mathbeginner: see edit.

Comment: Thanks! I'll now try to use the same method for the second estimator. Thanks for all the effort!